# Integrate spring with hibernate using maven dependencies

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I had made a project using Spring & Hibernate with maven as tool organiser.

Sometimes back it seems that the following version of hibernate was stopped/removed/something from all the repositories

```xml
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations
        </artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, I switched to following versions to resolve all the compilation related issues etc:

```xml
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <!--version>3.3.0.ga</version-->
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>


    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations
        </artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        <!--version>3.5.6-Final</version-->
    </dependency>
```

Though al the compilation related issues got resolved, I am facing lot of problems trying to deploy the war file created using these hibernate versions and spring dependencies (though the war is getting generated successfully, while deployment Spring & hibernate are giving some errors).

Basically, I want to use the latest version of Spring & Hibernate and create a web application war file.

I would really appreciate if some one can list the set of spring & hibernate maven dependencies which are successfully available in all repositories along with the list of repositories to create a successful web application, preferably if you have successfully deployed and used that war.

These are the spring related dependencies and other dependencies I have used in my application:

```xml
  <properties>
    <servlet-api.version>2.5.0</servlet-api.version>
    <maven.jetty.version>6.1.10</maven.jetty.version>
    <!--ehcache.version>1.2.3</ehcache.version-->
    <net.sf.ehcache.version>2.2.0</net.sf.ehcache.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>in</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.jetty.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin
            </artifactId>
            <version>${enunciate.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.terracotta.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>tc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-integration</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>terminate-integration</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>terminate-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!--
          dependency> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.12</version> </dependency
      -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple
        </groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context
        </artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
          test temp dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.springframework.core </artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency
      -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web
        </artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet
        </artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.beans
        </artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.oxm
        </artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet
        </artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--
          test temp dependency> <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-rc4</version> </dependency
      -->

    <!--
          test temp dependency> <groupId>org.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
          <artifactId>quartz</artifactId> <version>1.6.1</version> </dependency
      -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context.support
        </artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
          test temp dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction </artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency
      -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
          dependency> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.14</version> </dependency
      -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>enunciate-rt</artifactId>
        <version>${enunciate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-xfire</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-xfire-rt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-gwt-rt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-amf-rt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-rest-rt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>enunciate-jaxws-ri-rt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>enunciate-jersey-rt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--
          temp testdependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
          <artifactId>enunciate-jaxws-ri-rt</artifactId>
          <version>${enunciate.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions>
          </dependency
      -->


    <!--
          temp test dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
          <artifactId>enunciate-jersey-rt</artifactId>
          <version>${enunciate.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions>
          </dependency
      -->


    <!--
          temp test dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
          <artifactId>enunciate-spring-app-rt </artifactId>
          <version>${enunciate.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions>
          </dependency
      -->

    <!--
          temp test dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
          <artifactId>enunciate-rest-rt</artifactId>
          <version>${enunciate.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions>
          </dependency
      -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-cache</artifactId>
        <version>0.8a</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!--
                    Exclusions to make up for the fact that the 0.8a POM for
                    spring-modules-cache isn't marking many of its optional
                    dependencies as optional. TO DO - add some more exclusions if
                    possible
                -->

            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>gigaspaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>gigaspaces-ce</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>webster</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jmx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>start</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-minimal</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>reggie</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-cache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jcs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-system</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsk-platform</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>mahalo</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsk-lib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>boot</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--
          dependency> <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations
          </groupId> <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations </artifactId>
          <version>1.1.2</version> <type>jar</type> <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency
      -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--dependency>
          <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
          <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
          <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
      </dependency-->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-terracotta</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
        <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-1.2-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>local-simplecaptcha</groupId>
        <artifactId>local-simplecaptcha</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/simplecaptcha-1.2.1.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Other technologies I am using :

EhCache, Solr, MySQL

The old setup used to work fantastically in my first computer but when I switched to new system (computer), all of a sudden lot of hibernate dependencies etc went missing and I did lot of trial & error resolving various dependencies for Spring & Hibernate.

I would really appreciate if some one can give me  a sober solution so hat I can get my webapp back to working mode

I was working on some maven 2 version, but if I have to switch to maven 3 etc, I am ready for that too. I just need a solution which works end to end without the need to disturb my code.

Comment: Are you planning to use Hibernate 3.5.6.  Present Hibernate version is 4.1.  Maven repository for hibernate artifact is: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/.  And Spring 3.1.1 latest version supports Hibernate 4.1.

Comment: Consider using external links for big code excerpts, like: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

An example with spring, hibernate, mysql, junit and jsp-oriented web application.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>MyApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- Version number of Spring -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<!-- JBoss repository for Hibernate -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules.
    Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
    Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
    Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs
    (org.springframework.beans.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
    Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs
    (org.springframework.aop.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Application Context
(depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container
and is generally always defined-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail,      Quartz, and Freemarker integration. Define this if you need any of these integrations-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
    Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
    (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
    Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API
    (org.springframework.jdbc.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA and iBatis.
(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX,
Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and
Portlet Environments
(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another
web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments
  (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
  Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as
  Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container
    (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the
integration testing framework and unit testing stubs-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax servlet is used for HttpSession and HttpServletRequest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency used for jsp pages -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
</build>
```